# What are the underlying Windows7 mechanics that are responsible for opening selected files via key 'Enter'?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, batch

I need to create a batch script that opens `n` files, of same type and same suffix, with program `p`,
without creating `n` instances of `p` (i. e. use multiple tabs instead of multiple instances).

For some file types (and applications) it's enough to type

`cmd /c <file_1.ext> <file_2.ext> <file_n.ext>`

This opens all the files within one instance of the registered standard application for the file extension `etx`.

But some programs don't support this kind of start up via command line and **only** open `file_1.etx` given above argument list.

Inexplicably selecting all the files via mouse and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> yields the desired behavior.
So what are the underlying mechanics that Windows applies here? How can I simulate this behavior with a batch script?

---

I already tried `start <file_1.ext> <file_2.ext> <file_n.ext>` and `start <program.exe> <file_1.ext> <file_2.ext> <file_n.ext>`.

<sub>The Windows version and the program `p` I was refering to:
Microsoft Windows Version [Version 6.1.7601], Teamcenter Visualization Base / VisView.exe</sub>

Comment: `start file_1.ext` will launch "things" in a similar manner as pressing enter on the same.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that I already tried this... Sry, I'm a little bit tired.

Comment: Sorry for not reading your Q fully, `... opens all the files within one instance of the registered standard application ...` - that will always require the application to support having multiple files open in one instance; that is fully dependent on application internals. Either look up in documentation on the specific application or expect it to be limited to what you can make it do by tinkering.

Comment: But it does work via GUI (select via mouse + enter), as described in the question - so there must be some kind of underlying calls that happen to enable this functionality.

Comment: That might then be a sequence of calls, as in programming using e.g. C/C++ - might be you could be more lucky asking at e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @mike: So `<program.exe> <file_1.ext> <file_2.ext>` (without getting *start* involved) doesn't work and opens only file_1.ext? How about `<program.exe> <file_1.ext>` followed by `<program.exe> <file_2.ext>`? That opens two instances of program.exe? Is there an option in the program to restrict it to a single running instance?

Comment: It would help if you could tell what the program is. The mechanism used can be read up in the registry.